# Internet not working even though connected

Tags: internet, connection

I have been running Ubuntu on my Dell laptop for almost half a year. Wifi has had some connectivity issues in the past but now all of a sudden I cannot access the internet at all. I have tried both WIFI and wired connections, both say that they are connected in the network manager but I am unable to access the internet. Tried other laptops on the same network and internet is working fine...also this icon is appearing in the top right, not sure if this helps. Help fixing this issue today would be very much appreciated, I really need my laptop tonight and tomorrow and can't afford to have no internet!! I can't believe all the other devices on the network are working but not my Ubuntu laptop. Please help!! Thanks

Also I even tried using my phone as a hotspot to completely get onto a new network and I get the same issue even though my phones internet is working, so it is definitely some kind of issue with my laptop and not with my network.

Comment: I tried posting a picture of the icon in the top right tray but it is too big. The icon is 3 boxes connected with a line. If anyone needs me to run commands to run diagnostic or ask for any more info or hardware specs please let me know and I can do it!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone, turns out I had a vpn killswitch active that I could not see. The vpn I use is a cli so there is no indicator when it gets triggered....